# Lodash way of finding if deep object has a specific key value, not knowing if deep object exists?

Tags: javascript, lodash

There are a fair number of questions asking how to find if an object has a specific key value, but they are all plain JS implementations and couldn't find an answer that was Lodash-ey.

I know in lodash I can find deep objects without chaining `&&`s with

```
_.get(myObj, "some.Deep.Object")
```

I also know I can find where a value for a key matches what I'm trying to find in a collection with

```
_.find(myCollection, {id: THE_VALUE_I_WANT}
```

My question is: is there a way to do both of these in one go?

I tried

```
_.find("myObj.some.Deep.Object", {id: THE_VALUE_I_WANT})
```

but `find` needs an actual object to work with. I know I could nest the commands inside each other, do something like

```
_.find(_.get(myObj, "some.Deep.Object", []), {id: THE_VALUE_I_WANT})
```

I have a suspicion there is something I am missing in Lodash's docs that would do this with one call, rather than needing to nest two calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following:

```
_.find(myCollection, ['myObj.some.Deep.Object.id', THE_VALUE_I_WANT])
```